# Closed form of Harmonic series without digits 9 in its decimal representation

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

There is a question I've done before, that is

> In the Harmonic series $1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n+\cdots$, the fraction of $1/k$ is dropped if the decimal representation contains number digits 9, then the rest of the series is convergent.

the proof is simple to me. But a long time ago(for years), I was told by someone the convergent series has a closed form. Until now I review my notes recently, I remember that takes me much efforts but got no answer, Is it true, and how?

any method can be used such as real analysis(its more like Cantor Set), special functions(I've tried generating function and derivative before)

Comment: The binary analogue of this number is the Erdős–Borwein constant (sum of reciprocals of all positive integers whose binary representation contains no zero, $\sim 1.60669)$), and to my knowledge there is nothing like a closed form for that constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Borwein_constant

Comment: @Travis Thanks for your abs, I reviewed the Wikipedia, its linked to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-BorweinConstant.html, in there the poly gamma function used is acceptable. So that is why I still consider special functions may be useful.